# Where do I place decode code in a python script?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm new to python and my experience is minimal.

- UPDATE: adding full error message**

  ```
  "UnicodeDecodeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
   in ()
       36         df1 = df1.drop('LOCATION_DESCR',axis=1)
       37         filename = i+'_'+j+'_'+TODAY+'.xlsx'
  ---> 38         df1.to_excel(new_dir+'\\'+filename,index = False)
       39         print filename +' is created'
       40         summary.append([i,j,str(len(df1.index))])

  c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes)
     2125         formatter.write(excel_writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=startrow,
     2126                         startcol=startcol, freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
  -> 2127                         engine=engine)
     2128 
     2129     def to_json(self, path_or_buf=None, orient=None, date_format=None,

  c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.pyc in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine)
      660         writer.write_cells(formatted_cells, sheet_name,
      661                            startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol,
  --> 662                            freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
      663         if need_save:
      664             writer.save()

  c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)
     1603                 column=startcol + cell.col + 1
     1604             )
  -> 1605             xcell.value, fmt = self._value_with_fmt(cell.val)
     1606             if fmt:
     1607                 xcell.number_format = fmt

  c:\python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.pyc in value(self, value)
      270     def value(self, value):
      271         """Set the value and infer type and display options."""
  --> 272         self._bind_value(value)
      273 
      274     @property

  c:\python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.pyc in _bind_value(self, value)
      227 
      228         elif dt == "s":
  --> 229             value = self.check_string(value)
      230             if len(value) > 1 and value.startswith("="):
      231                 self.data_type = 'f'

  c:\python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.pyc in check_string(self, value)
      178         # convert to unicode string
      179         if not isinstance(value, unicode):
  --> 180             value = unicode(value, self.encoding)
      181         value = unicode(value)
      182         # string must never be longer than 32,767 characters

  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 14: invalid start byte" error message.
  ```

I have tried adding 
my_string.encode('utf-8')
where my_string is actually a file name getting created. I know this is most likely incorrect but I do not know what string the error is referring to.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I narrow down what the error is pointing to?
2. Where in the code do I place the decode code I will have to produce?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: where is code which gives this error? Show it in question (not comment) as text (not image)

Comment: first you should check what encoding uses code `0xa0` - it can be different encoding, not `utf-8`, ie. `latin1`, and you may need `open( ..., encoding=other_encoding)`

Comment: @furas, thank you for your comments. I have added the full error above.

Comment: Windows can use  `cp1250` or `latin1` (or similar if you use native chars) for data and you may need to use `to_excel( ..., encoding="cp1250")` to save it

Comment: It looks like you are using the old python 2 where encoded and decoded strings can be a real nightmare. If at all possible, move to python 3. Python 2 is end-of-life and unicode string handling is one reason why.

Comment: I was not able to get it to work :( I am unsure of what string to even put as the object needing encoded.